# Get hostname of Http Referer in Nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers, http-referer, access-log

I'm using Nginx as a web server.

Is there any way to extract `http_referer_hostname` and put it in access log.

For example: if `$http_referer` is `"http://example.com/?somedata"`, how to log only hostname part (`example.com`) to the `access.log` line?

Answer (score 1):

Use [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map):

```
map $http_referer $http_referer_hostname {
    ~^.*://([^?/]+).*$ $1;
}
```

The desired result will be stored in $http_referer_hostname

EDIT: the regexp is changed, thanks to @phiphi

Comment: This regex does not work properly. the capture group (.+) captures more than it should when there are multiple / afterwards.
Better to exclude / and ? from the capture group: `~^.*://([^/?]+) $1;`